# Sending listBox data between Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello im new to to the C# stuff I'm just learning.

So my problem is that i want to send my `listBox1` items from `Form1` to `Form2` that has a `listBox2` and display the items of the `listBox1` in the `Form2`.

Im From Slovenia so newermind the Form names and other entries

This is the first Form called:

```
public partial class TopliNapitki : Form
{
    public TopliNapitki()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    int pomozno=0;

    decimal cena = 0;
    decimal kava = 1.10m; 
    decimal cap = 1.30m;
    decimal bKava = 1.60m;
    decimal kavaM = 1.30m;
    decimal caj = 1.30m;
    decimal kakav = 1.70m;
    decimal vCokolada = 1.80m;
    decimal lKava = 2.50m;

    public string _textBox1
    {
        get { return textBox1.Text; }
    }

    public string _listBox1
    {
        get { return listBox1.Text; }
    } 



    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form1 = new Form1();
        this.Close();
        form1.Show();  
    }

    int stetjeKava = 1;
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id=1;

        if (stetjeKava > 1)
        {
            listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex=id-1);
            listBox1.Items.Add(id + "." + "Kava" + " Cena:   " + kava + "x" + stetjeKava+"    " +cena);
            cena = cena + kava;
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(cena);
        }
        if (stetjeKava == 1)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(id + "." + "Kava" + " Cena:   " + kava + "x" + stetjeKava);
            cena = cena + kava;
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(cena);
        }
        stetjeKava = stetjeKava + 1;

        pomozno = pomozno + 1;
    }

    int stetjeCap=1;
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = 2;

        if (stetjeCap > 1)
        {
            listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex = id - 1);
            listBox1.Items.Add(id + "." + "Capuccino" + " Cena:   " + cap + "x" + stetjeCap + "    " + cena);
            cena = cena + cap;
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(cena);
        }
        if (stetjeCap == 1)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(id + "." + "Capuccino" + " Cena:   " + cap + "x" + stetjeCap);
            cena = cena + cap;
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(cena);
        }
        stetjeCap = stetjeCap + 1;
    }

    int stetjeBKava = 1;
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = 3;

        if (stetjeBKava > 1)
        {
            listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex = id - 1);
            listBox1.Items.Add(id + "." + "Bela Kava" + " Cena:   " + bKava + "x" + stetjeBKava + "    " + cena);
            cena = cena + bKava;
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(cena);
        }
        if (stetjeBKava == 1)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(id + "." + "Bela Kava" + " Cena:   " + bKava + "x" + stetjeBKava);
            cena = cena +bKava;
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(cena);
        }
        stetjeBKava = stetjeBKava + 1;
    }

    int stetjeKavaM = 1;
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = 4;

        if (stetjeKavaM > 1)
        {
            listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex = id - 1);
            listBox1.Items.Add(id + "." + "Kava z Mlekom" + " Cena:   " + kavaM + "x" + stetjeKavaM + "    " + cena);
            cena = cena + kavaM;
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(cena);
        }
        if (stetjeKavaM == 1)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(id + "." + "Kava z Mlekom" + " Cena:   " + kavaM + "x" + stetjeKavaM);
            cena = cena + kavaM;
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(cena);
        }
        stetjeKavaM = stetjeKavaM + 1;
    }

    int stetjeCaj = 1;
    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = 5;

        if (stetjeCaj > 1)
        {
            listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex = id - 1);
            listBox1.Items.Add(id + "." + "Čaj" + " Cena:   " + caj + "x" + stetjeCaj + "    " + cena);
            cena = cena + caj;
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(cena);
        }
        if (stetjeCaj == 1)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(id + "." + "Čaj" + " Cena:   " + caj + "x" + stetjeCaj);
            cena = cena + caj;
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(cena);
        }
        stetjeCaj = stetjeCaj + 1;
    }

    int stetjeKakav = 1;
    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = 6;

        if (stetjeKakav > 1)
        {
            listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex = id - 1);
            listBox1.Items.Add(id + "." + "Kakav" + " Cena:   " + kakav + "x" + stetjeKakav + "    " + cena);
            cena = cena + kakav;
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(cena);
        }
        if (stetjeKakav == 1)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(id + "." + "Kakav" + " Cena:   " + kakav + "x" + stetjeKakav);
            cena = cena + kakav;
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(cena);
        }
        stetjeKakav = stetjeKakav + 1;
    }

    int stetjeVCoko = 1;
    private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = 7;

        if (stetjeVCoko > 1)
        {
            listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex = id - 1);
            listBox1.Items.Add(id + "." + "Vroča čokolada" + " Cena:   " + vCokolada + "x" + stetjeVCoko + "    " + cena);
            cena = cena + vCokolada;
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(cena);
        }
        if (stetjeVCoko == 1)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(id + "." + "Vroča čokolada" + " Cena:   " + vCokolada + "x" + stetjeVCoko);
            cena = cena + vCokolada;
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(cena);
        }
        stetjeVCoko = stetjeVCoko + 1;
    }

    int stetjeLKava = 1;
    private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = 8;

        if (stetjeLKava > 1)
        {
            listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex = id - 1);
            listBox1.Items.Add(id + "." + "Ledena kava" + " Cena:   " + lKava + "x" + stetjeLKava + "    " + cena);
            cena = cena + lKava;
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(cena);
        }
        if (stetjeLKava == 1)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(id + "." + "Ledena kava" + " Cena:   " + lKava + "x" + stetjeLKava);
            cena = cena + lKava;
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(cena);
        }
        stetjeLKava = stetjeLKava + 1;
    }

    private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form1 = new Racun();
        form1.Show();
        form1._textBox = _textBox1;
        form1._listBox = _listBox1;
        this.Close();
        form1.Show();  
    }

    }
}
```

The second Form:

```
    public partial class Racun : Form
{
    public Racun()
    {
        InitializeComponent();     
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form1 = new Form1();
        this.Close();
        form1.Show();  
    }

    public string _textBox
    {
        set { textBox1.Text = value; }
    }

    public string _listBox
    {
        set { listBox1.Items.Add(value); }
    }
}
```

}

I have this set up for sending data for listBox but it doesnt work on Form1:

```
    public string _listBox1
    {
        get { return listBox1.Text; }
    } 

    private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form1 = new Racun();
        form1.Show();
        form1._listBox = _listBox1;
        this.Close();
        form1.Show();  
    }
```

And the Form2 has this in it:

```
    public string _listBox
    {
        set { listBox1.Items.Add(value); }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  It would be useful to see code that you've already written.  Your data source for your listbox1 for example. Also any errors that you are receiving.

Comment: No errors, and thanks for the welcoming. :)

Comment: In this code, you are instantiating `Form1()` but dont have a form called form1.  Wouldnt in your button click on the first form you would call `var form1 = new Rancun()`?

Comment: as i said im from slovenia i writen it in my language but my Form1-TopliNapitki, Form2-Racun. I have alot more forms in my project the main form called Form1 has buttons that go to other forms, but i dont need it now because its already done. I just dont know how to send data from first form to second form.

Comment: yes: 

Error 1 The name '_listBox' does not exist in the current context

Comment: It sounds like you have both scope issues AND variable naming issues.  Giving meaningful names to your objects helps you keep track of them in the future.  Also, you dont want to access `TopiNapitki._listBox` from `Rancun`.  Pass variables via the constructor or properties to the new form.

Comment: I managed to send a textBox value to the Racun Form and show it on the textBox. But i did the same thing with this but it doesnt work.
This method that you showed me doesnt work for me it just ads new errors. Im not so good with the C# language.

Comment: Its almost like a cash register in bars that you order some drink and when you press a button the drink is added to the listBox and then when you press a button it sends you to a form that you see what you have ordered.

Comment: now this line is giving me errors: 

get { return listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();

Comment: Error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the values in the constructor:

```
string _listValue;
public Racun(string listValue)
{
    InitializeComponent(); 
    _listValue = listValue;
}
```

It would be called like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var form1 = new Rancun(_listBox);
    this.Close();
    form1.Show();  
}
```

I also think you have a bug when trying to get the selected item out of the listbox.  It should be called like this:

```
get { return listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString(); }
```